# PHP foreach array get first 9 results then second 9

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Using PHP foreach how would I get only the first 9 results in one foreach and only the second 9 in another.

Something like

> foreach {$shops[1 - 9] as $shop) {

```
 foreach {$shops[10 - 18] as
 $shop) {
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: `array_slice` is what you want.

Comment: @Robin Knight you can make a little effort you ask a similar question a few minute ago

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php you can get more option

Comment: not sure if you need this but you should also know, it's better to limit your query results with LIMIT and OFFSET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`:](http://us.php.net/array_slice)

```
foreach(array_slice($shops,0,9) as $shop){
   // etc.
}

foreach(array_slice($shops,9,9) as $shop){
   // etc.
}
```

Comment: Side question: how could you do this to an array of unknown length? 1, 25, 122, not just 18?

Comment: You can easily check count() to get the size of the array.   But, if you're trying to divide it into chunks of equal size and modulo chunksize != 0, you will have to have logic to handle that last chunk being of a different size.  Nothing in the array_slice call as written would break, though.  In the case of my example above, it would return UP TO 9 items per-chunk.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `for` loop instead?

```
for (int $i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
{
    $shop = $shops[$i];
}
```

Then you could do another with `$i = 10..19`.  If you must use `foreach` then have a counter you increment and `break;` or use `array_slice` as others have suggested.

Comment: this could working if there's nothing to do with the value in arrays

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
foreach (array_slice($shops, 0, 9) as $shop) {
  ...
}
```

and

```
foreach (array_slice($shops, 9, 9) as $shop) {
  ...
}
```

??

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (array_chunk($shops, 9) as $section) {
    // Do some logic on each section
    foreach ($section as $shop) {
        // Do some logic on each shop
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is much more sophisticated than others.

Answer (score 0):

using  [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)  you can split your array into two then you can do this

```
$my_array = array('1','2',...,'18');

$first_array = array_slice($my_array,0,9);
$second_array = array_slice($my_array,9,18);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop instead.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++)
{
    $shop = $shops[$i];
}

for ($i = 9; $i < 18; $i++)
{
    $shop = $shops[$i];
}
```