# Showing specific number of <div>'s on jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

On each page this button is on there will be 24 `.preview-containers`.

I need to show the first 9 `.preview-containers` initially and then on each `#show-more` button click show an additional 9 until they are all shown.

I also need to update the value in the button to reflect how many `.preview-containers` are still hidden.

```
   var allContainers = $('.preview-container').hide();
    $('#show-more').html('Show more works ('+allContainers.length+')');
    allContainers.slice(0,9).show();

$('#show-more').on('click', function(){
    $('#show-more').html('Show more works ('+allContainers.length+')');
    allContainers.slice(9,18).fadeIn();
});
```

So far the code successfully hides all 24 on page load, how can I update this code to show the first 9 and then show an additional 9 each time the `#show-more` button is pressed?

Comment: what is `array_slice` ?

Comment: Found on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6694398/php-foreach-array-get-first-9-results-then-second-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```js
var allContainers = $('.preview-container:gt(8)').hide();
$('#show-more').html('Show more works (' + allContainers.length + ')').on('click', function() {
  $('.preview-container:hidden:lt(9)').fadeIn();
  $('#show-more').html('Show more works (' + $('.preview-container:hidden').length + ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show-more">
  button
</button>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
<div class="preview-container">
  div
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly and is much more efficient

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you need me to explain the few lines of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, make a step, `increment` it on `every click` and show `.prev-container:`

Check **snippet below**

```
 var step=9;
var allContainers = $('.preview-container').hide();
$('#show-more').on('click', function(){
 var showMore= allContainers.length-step;
  if(showMore<0){
    showMore=0;
  }
    $('#show-more').html('Show more works ('+showMore+')');
    allContainers.slice(0,step).fadeIn();
  step+=9;
});
```

```js
var step = 9;
var allContainers = $('.preview-container').hide();
$('#show-more').on('click', function() {
  var showMore = allContainers.length - step;
  if (showMore < 0) {
    showMore = 0;
  }
  $('#show-more').html('Show more works (' + showMore + ')');
  allContainers.slice(0, step).fadeIn();
  step += 9;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show-more">Show more</button>

<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
<li class="preview-container">Some Text</li>
```